# Quickest way to learn Linq to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am developing my first ASP.NET MVC application using the Entity Framework.  I have no previous .NET experience, although I'm fluent in other OO languages.  I am having trouble understanding Linq to Entity query expressions, more specifically its syntax and how to render the results on an ASP page.

For example, I am joining three tables (entities) together and trying to iterate over the results, but I get all sorts of type errors.  Every example I find on Google, SO, or MSFT hasn't been straightforward and each site takes their own approach.  I looked at the book Programming Entity Framework, but this too seems to be over my head at the moment.

I am looking for clear, concise examples of executing the equivalent of complex multiple joins and iterating over the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've just started this myself, and I bought both [the wrox book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ADO-NET-3-5-with-LINQ-and-the-Entity-Framework.productCd-047018261X.html) and the [o'reilly](http://learnentityframework.com/) one.

I've found the wrox one a little more inaccessible - the language used in it is a bit heavier, and the layout/organisation isn't quite so 'flowy' (is that a word? hehe).

The o'reilly one on the other hand is a cracking read, and really does lead you nicely through it.  It's available on safaribooks too if you have a sub, I got it from Amazon who seemed one of the few places to have it in stock.  Very much recommended.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at these samples - http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/03/13/101-linq-samples-updated.aspx

i picked up the concept from these examples itself

[Scott Guthrie's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) blog has also really good explanation & samples

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should get yourself a good book on the subject.  Since you have no previous experience in .NET a general book that covers LINQ might be a start and then a ASP.NET-MVC specific one.

Perhaps the reason why being fluent in "other" OO languages isn't helping is that LINQ isn't an OO language, its much more functional and therefore takes a different way of reasoning to understand well.